# Return class of List<T> and int from Action to another Action ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, list, redirecttoaction

i have to send `List<Sale>` and `ID`  to anther Action method which is defined in class `SaleWithPatientID`.

here is code of action which will save data in `DB` and in `List`.

```
public ActionResult Create(Sale sale ,string[] product)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    SaleWithPatientID all = new SaleWithPatientID();
                    for (int x=0; x<product.Length; x++)
                    {
                        sale.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        sale.LabTest_ID =int.Parse(pro[x]);
                        db.Sales.Add(sale);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //adding in list
                        all.Sales.Add(sale); 
                    }
                    //Hard coded patient id (example)
                    all.Patient = 123;
                    return RedirectToAction("Print", all);
                }
             }
```

> `Sale` is the table in DB

Here is Class which have List of Sale and Patient_ID

```
public class SaleWithPatientID
{
    public int? Patient { get; set; }
    public List<Sale> Sales =new List<Sale>();


}
```

and here i wana get Data

```
public ActionResult Print(SaleWithPatientID obj)
    {         
        return View(obj);
    }
```

here i got `obj.Patient = 123` and `obj.Sales=null`

i'm getting only `Patient` and the `List of Sale` is Null.

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to redirect results?

Comment: You're declaring `public List<Sale> Sales` as a field, not a property. If you want to use `List<T>` property, you should use `for` loop and generate the elements for it, then in postback it will receive element values (unfortunately you're not including view code at this time).

Comment: yes. want to redirect result. #Rosdi Kasim